# Can SPARK 3.1 push metrics on Prometheus? Is there a handler?

Tags: push, prometheus, metrics, spark3

I am investigating if spark 3.1 and PPrometheus have push mechanisms between them.
I know it's possible to pull but I'd like to send the metrics from Spark to Prometheus.